# How to automate a task on a website, but many times?

Tags: javascript, node.js, virtual-machine, hosting, puppeteer

Lemme elaborate. So basically, what I'm trying to do is use puppeteer to automate a scrape of my friend's website. The puppeteer code for performing a single scrape is done already. However, I'm looking to do this process a lot of times, possibly thousands.

I've noticed that the puppeteer code takes like 45-60 seconds to run a single time. So if I did something like this within my code:

```
    for(let a = 0; a < 10000; a++) {
       //puppeteer code for a single scrape
    }
```

that would take 450,000 seconds minimum, which is over 5 days. Is there a way I can possibly split the task up somehow? Servers, maybe? Virtual machines? I'm not well versed in this area; I've only had to write puppeteer scripts that only need to execute once on command. Not thousands of times in a row. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: You don't want to scrape everything at once, probably neither your machine nor the server would handle that. Nor do you want to run everything in serial, since that'll take ages. Maybe have 5 or 10 scrapes going on at once, or something? If each is only retrieving a single page, you could probably up that number

Comment: Just keep pupperteer open, if the website is dynamic just use a timer to do you stuff again.  If the site is not dynamic, just do a refresh..  Also for scraping other pages don't fire up another instance of pupperteer, just navigate to the new page, again using the same instance.

Comment: @CertainPerformance that's what i'm looking to do. I was thinking of trying to set up a few dozen scrapes. Thing is, I have no idea how to do that.

Comment: @Keith most of that 45-60 seconds is spent on the actual website. Say I keep puppeteer open, and just log out/refresh. Maybe the time per iteration goes down to 30-45 seconds. We're still talking 300,000 seconds minimum if I wanna do this 10,000 times. It's really not feasible for me to just run this in serial.

Comment: Firing up multiple puppeteers won't gain you anything.  If you want to scrape multple pages, open multiple tabs in the same instance as your running pupperteer.  I used this technqiue a while back to scrape hundreds of pages from gambling websites.. ;)

Comment: @Keith could one computer really handle that? Imagine 100 tabs, all scraping that webpage 100 times each. My 2 year old laptop can barely handle minecraft. I doubt it'd be able to handle 100 tabs

Comment: 100 might be a bit much (or it might not be), but 10 would probably work, though it depends on the operations being performed

Comment: Try it manually, see how many pages you can open in chrome on said computer.  So are you saying you have multiple computers doing this.   Even so, what I said is still relevant.  Making 1 computer efficient at scaping means it will scale even better when you have more :)

Comment: @CertainPerformance is there a way I could push that to a server somehow? Have 10 websites running the script or something?

Comment: Have you heard of docker / kubernetes, you certainly can push to mutlple servers.  Be fore warned, it might cost you.. :_

Comment: @Keith okay, I'll do that for now. And no, I'm saying that I _want_ to have multiple computers doing this. Have like an army of 100 machines so that I could do 10000 scrapes in a little over an hour

Comment: @Keith woahhh....$750 per node, per year?? I mean thanks for taking your time to suggest that, but if I bought even 10 nodes I'd be burning through my savings

Comment: Yes, it's certainly possible.  But also remember what @CertainPerformance said , if you doing this to your friends website, he might not be your friend for long if your not careful.. :)

Comment: @Keith he knows lol it's not like this is a secret

Comment: Yes, it's not cheap.. We use dedicated boxes, and in theory you can setup your own kubernetes cluster.  Not done it myself, I've set up my own docker registry and do it manually doing docker pull etc.  So if you have access to spare 100 machines this would be cheaper.